# jQuery accordion assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, accordion

I have come across this code that I have tried to add to but I am afraid that I have made of mess of it. I am not very experienced with Jquery or web design and I need help finding what I have done wrong and how I can be more efficient.

Is there a better/more efficient way to write this code?

It has some bugs...

- Displays all divs upon load. I would like it to just show one that I can select.
- When it animates the text jumps around for some reason.
- Sometimes the divs will animate up but not down.

Here is a link to what it looks like right now: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14080718/Final/NeedHelp.html

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // the currently loaded section
        var curLoaded = 'about';

        // navigation trigger
        $('#navbar a').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this)
            var target = $this.attr('href').split('#')[1];
            var $contentContainer = $('#contentContainer');
            var oldPos = 0;
            var newPos = 200;

            // add a click handler to each A tag
            $this.click(function(){
                // if the container isn't open, then open it
                if ($contentContainer.css('height') == '') {
                    // trigger the animation
                    $contentContainer.animate({
                        height: newPos
                    },"slow", function(){
                        // fade in the content
                        $('#' + target).fadeIn();
                    });
                } else {
                    if (curLoaded == target) {
                        $contentContainer.animate({
                            height: oldPos
                        },"slow", function(){
                            $('#content div').hide();
                        });
                    } else {
                        $contentContainer.animate({
                            height: oldPos
                        },"slow", function(){
                            $('#content div').hide();
                            $contentContainer.animate({
                                height: newPos
                            },"slow", function(){
                                $('#' + target).fadeIn();
                            });
                        });
                    }
                }
                curLoaded = target;

                return false;
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: The [codereview.SE] site is probably a better place for getting the type of feedback you're looking for.  SO is most useful for helping you out when you're stuck on a specific problem with a specific answer.  If wide-open discussion is likely, it probably isn't a great fit.  Check out [The FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see the types of questions that are best for this site.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: According to the [FAQ of CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq), debugging questions should not be there. 

NateGines: I think the bugs should be fixed first, then post it to CodeReview for a general review. So, please edit this question to contain only the questions about debugging (and not effectiveness) to be fit to SO. (I suppose the question on CodeReview will be closed because of the bugs, but feel free to repost to CR when bugs are fixed.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken a look at your page and took a quick stab at addressing some of the buggy behaviors.

For one thing, it looks like you were handling the case where the user clicks a nav link for a second time, by sliding the content div closed, but you were not handling if the user clicks the nav link a third time.  As a user, I would expect that the div would slide open or closed no matter how many times I clicked the link.

In order to fix that, I've added a check for whether or not the target element is visible, and I use that to decide whether to slide the content open or closed.  I've also added calls to the show and hide functions for the target and curloaded elements to ensure that the check for whether the element is visible will provide the expected result.

My revised code is below.  It's possible that the logic for some of the cases could be consolidated in order to simplify the code.

```
// navigation trigger 
$('#navbar a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var target = $this.attr('href').split('#')[1];
    var $contentContainer = $('#contentContainer');
    var oldPos = 0;
    var newPos = 200;

    // add a click handler to each A tag 
    $this.click(function() {
        // if the container isn't open, then open it 
        if ($contentContainer.css('height') === '') {
            // trigger the animation 
            $contentContainer.animate({
                    height: newPos
                }, "slow", function() {
                    // fade in the content 
                    $('#' + target).show().fadeIn();
                });
        } else {
            if (curLoaded == target) {
                if ($('#' + target).is(':visible')) {
                    $contentContainer.animate({
                            height: oldPos
                        }, "slow", function() {
                            $('#' + curLoaded).hide();
                            $('#content div').hide();
                        });
                } else {
                    $contentContainer.animate({
                            height: newPos
                        }, "slow", function() {
                            // fade in the content 
                            $('#' + target).show().fadeIn();
                        });
                }
            } else {
                $contentContainer.animate({
                        height: oldPos
                    }, "slow", function() {
                        $('#' + curLoaded).hide();
                        $('#content div').hide();
                        $contentContainer.animate({
                                height: newPos
                            }, "slow", function() {
                                $('#' + target).fadeIn();
                            });
                    });
            }
        }

        curLoaded = target;

        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: You are awesome! This works great now! If I wanted to add a class that would make the the accordion open, shut or toggle (like class="open", "close" or "toggle")? Ive tried a few things, but I keep breaking the page because I can seem to get the right syntax.

Comment: @Nate - You won't be able to achieve the animation effect of the opening and closing using a CSS class.  CSS just describes the visual style of the elements, and doesn't really have any concept of execution. You can add or remove a class on an element using jQuery, but there is no way to say "slowly apply this class to this element". You can, however, use CSS classes as flags on an element to instruct your jQuery code how to handle a particular element. i.e. use jQuery's selector syntax, "#navbar a.toggle" to find anchor tags inside of #navbar that have the toggle class applied.

Answer (score 1):

The css on this fiddler will help with all the divs initially showing up.  Can you explain the other 2 errors in more detail (I don't seem to notice them)

[Fiddler Code](http://jsfiddle.net/skyrim/w9m2k/4/)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddler code. It worked great! As for the other problems... It looks like if you click on one of the links in the nav the #contentContainer div shifts slightly, as well as the type in it. Also if you click a bunch of links in quick succession sometimes a div will shut and not open back up until another link is clicked. It doesnt seem to have these problems in fiddler, but id does in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post the code in the answer.  Answers on SO should be self-contained, in case other sites go down or people don't have access to it, and so that the post is more searchable.